# Blocking the listing of the apps other than Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, apk

> I don't want my apps to be listed in other un-official open source
> platforms such as apkpure, aptoide, apkmonk, etc.  It should be only
> available in the Google's Play Store and can be downloaded from their
> itself.
>
> **Is it possible to do so?**
>
> I searched and many of the popular apps are also available on
> unofficial platforms so curios how this apps are available on those
> markets and how to remove if we want?

*Thanks.*

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: To be honest it looks like there is no way to avoid listing by other third-party stores.
We have ended with checking the installation source and showing information that app was downloaded from an unofficial source and can't be used.